# Electrical system problem on 1997 Nissan XE, 2.4 -5 speed truck

Tags: electrical, nissan

I disconnected the battery cable on a 1997 Nissan XE,  2.4 -5 speed  truck to put on a new cable end because it was corroded, when I reconnected it all the idiot lights on the dash were off, the AC fan & alternator was not working.  The headlight, wipers, radio. and the starter & engine all worked.   When I used the factory cable end again they all  did come back a couple of times, but the last time they didn't.  I even bought a Diagnostic scan tool but it also wouldn't work. How can I reset or somehow fix everything? Also the "Shift Lock" fuse blew & was replaced every time.  All the other fuses are good.  Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I would bet you've got a connection issue, either at the battery or where the cables connect at the other end. You might want to see if there is corrosion anywhere on opposite end, as well as ensuring the connections are correctly tightened.

Comment: Curious if you see the lights come on and off if you wiggle the battery cables a bit

Comment: Headlights, radio, starter, fuel pump, wipers,  all work & engine runs.  All warning lamps on dash, AC fan, alternator, tail lights & brake lights don't work.  Thinking maybe a fusible link or something like that?